# Use of undeclared type "myClass" when dynamically creating view controllers

Tags: swift

I am wanting to get a `myClass` value assigned with a type, then instantiate that from the storyboard.

```
func detailViewControllerClasses(index: Int) -> UIViewController {
        let myClass = [CollectionViewController().self, CollectionViewController().self, CollectionViewController().self, CollectionViewController().self][index]


        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewController") as? myClass else {
            fatalError("Unable to instatiate a ViewController from the storyboard.")
        }
    }
```

on the `guard let` line the compiler says "undeclared variable myClass". I declared it a few lines up with no errors or warnings. Why is this error happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate your `CollectionViewControllers` before accessing `.self`. Therefore you are not creating an array of class but an array of instances. Remove the `()`

```
func detailViewControllerClasses(index: Int) -> UIViewController {
    let myClass = [CollectionViewController.self, CollectionViewController.self, CollectionViewController.self, CollectionViewController.self][index]


    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewController") as? myClass else {
        fatalError("Unable to instatiate a ViewController from the storyboard.")
    }
}
```